# Text wraparound in table headings

Tags: tables

In a tabular or table environment, I have table headings that are long, so I write them in two lines separated by `\\`

This does the job, but doesn’t look good. Is there a way to get the text to wraparound naturally in the heading?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Maybe `\multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{....<long title>}` but hard to tell without an explicit code example from your side.

Comment: You can use a `\parbox{width}{text}`. This is added automatically in a `p{width}` column. Others columns types (m,b,X,L,C,R,J,etc) make also this with different vertical  and horizontal alignments. See manuals of  `array`, `tabularx and `tabulary` packages.

Comment: Thanks Schrodinger’s Cat. This works with some tweaking of the column’s width. But it introduces an extra space between the top rule and the column title. I haven’t figured out how to eliminate the extra space. I tried \vspace with a negative argument, but that bombed. I’ll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Fran. I’ll try your suggestions and report back

Comment: Fran, the \parbox command worked best. No extra vertical space was inserted. As expected, the command required adjusting the column width to avoid artifacts such as hyphenated words. Thanks again for your suggestion.